# Ionic 4 + Angular FingerprintAIO not a supported plugin?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I believe that the plugin `FingerprintAIO` might not be supported on `ionic 4`.

When I use the following commands to install the `cordova` and `ionic` plugins all seems fine:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio
npm install @ionic-native/fingerprint-aio
```

In my `app.module.ts` I have the following code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {FingerprintAIO} from '@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    FingerprintAIO
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

However where I list FingerprintAIO as a provider I get the following error:

```
TS2322: Type 'FingerprintAIOOriginal' is not assignable to the type 'Provider'. Type 'FingerprintAIOOriginal' is not assignable to the type 'FactoryProvider'. Property 'provide' is missing in type 'FingerprintAIOOriginal'
```

Any ideas what's causing that? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your import from

```
import {FingerprintAIO} from '@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio';
```

to

```
import {FingerprintAIO} from '@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio/ngx';
```

as mentioned on the usage section of the [official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fingerprint-aio)

Comment: Trying that with a clean project now

Comment: @LewisSmith any luck?

Comment: Doesn't error now, having a permissions error, but you got me past the issue so that's the correct answer